# communicating between iframe and parent window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

in an article where Sencha disputes facebooks claim that html5 is slow,they suggest that there's a way to create a framework that would allow for seamless communication between an iframe and the parent window. How would this be achieved? not looking for code examples, just ideas. thanks

> So the Fastbook app is the first to make use of a brand new “Sandbox
>   Container” which programmatically detaches complex views and renders
>   them into their own iframes, and thus partitioning the DOM tree. This
>   special container doesn't need any extra handling at the application
>   level, so it's seamless to developers (i.e., any component added to
>   this container will be sandboxed automatically). **But it does come at
>   a cost: events, positioning, styling, and JavaScript code have to be
>   proxied between the parent window and the child sandboxes**. This is
>   complicated, so without a robust and properly architected framework,
>   it is very difficult to implement. Sandboxing allows layouts to be
>   isolated, and therefore keeps the primary DOM tree as light as
>   possible. To bring balance to the Force, Sandbox Containers must be
>   used wisely

.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/postaljs/postal.xframe

Comment: I would recommend https://github.com/tildeio/oasis.js

Answer (score 0):

something like http://easyxdm.net/wp/ takes care of it by using PostMessageTransport